# String index out of range -8

Tags: java

I don't absolutely see a reason why the index is out of range. 
the start is from the letters `atg` in the string `ataaactatgttttaaatgt` and ends with `taa`. What am I missing here?

Edit: This is the line right here

`String subStr1 = dna.substring(start,stop1);`

```
/**

 *
 * @author Duke Software Team 
 */
import edu.duke.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TagFinder2 {


  public String findProtein(String dna) {
    int start = dna.indexOf("atg");

    int stop1 = dna.indexOf("tag", start+3);
    int stop2 = dna.indexOf("tga",start+3);
    int stop3 = dna.indexOf("taa",start+3);


    String subStr1 = dna.substring(start,stop1);
    String subStr2 = dna.substring(start,stop2);
    String subStr3 = dna.substring(start,stop3);

    String result;

    if( subStr1.length() % 3 ==0 ){
      return subStr1;
    } else if (subStr2.length()%3==0){
      return subStr2;
    } else if (subStr3.length()%3 == 0) {
      return subStr3;
    } else {

      return "";
    }
  }

  private void stopCodon(String gene){
    //This prints out the last 3 characters of the gene

    String stopCodon = gene.substring(gene.length() - 3);
    System.out.println(stopCodon);
  }

  public void testing() {
    String a = "ataaactatgttttaaatgt";
    String b = "acatgataacctaag";
    String c = "AATGCTAGTTTAAATCTGA";

    String result = findProtein(a);

    stopCodon(result);

  }
  //public String stopCodon(String dna){
  //   return 
  //  }


}
```

Comment: Which line exactly throws the Exception? Did you try and debug the code and check the values of your start and stop variables? e.g. stop1 will be -1 as there is no "tag" in the string you mention.

Comment: You can print out the values of your variables and find it out yourself. Asking something like this from us is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Adittionally there is no `tag` in your String. And `0%3` is also equal to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int stop1 = dna.indexOf("tag", start+3);
```

the `String` `a` does not contain the text `tag` and thus returns -1. Therefore, you end up calling

```
String subStr1 = dna.substring(start,stop1);
```

with parameters 7 and -1 which result in AIOOB.

From the docs:

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or
>   endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or
>   beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze or debug your code, you will find `stop1=-1,start=7`. When `substring(7,-1)`, how could it not go wrong?

[Click here to show the debug message picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc1Jq.png)